# How to interpret all fields of `utmpdump /var/log/utmp`

Tags: tty

I'd like to monitor logged in sessions, include how they logged in (physical console or SSH), and how long that session has existed for.

It seems like `utmpdump /var/log/utmp` has that information, but I can find't the documentation that explains all the fields. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 7):

The fields are (member names of `struct utmp` in parantheses - see `man 5 utmp`):

1. Type of record (`ut_type`)
2. PID of login process (`ut_pid`)
3. Terminal name suffix, or `inittab(5)` ID (`ut_id`)
4. Username (`ut_user`)
5. Device name or tty - "`/dev/`" (`ut_line`)
6. Hostname for remote login, or kernel version for run-level messages (`ut_host`)
7. Internet address of remote host (`ut_addr_v6`)
8. Time entry was made (`ut_time` or actually `ut_tv.tv_sec`)

The possible values for the first field (`ut_type` or "type of record") are explained in `utmp(5)` (`6` for example is `LOGIN_PROCESS`, or "Session leader process for user login").

Comment: Can you be more specific about runlevel type of record? How the actual runlevel is written there?

Comment: This cannot be easily answered in a general way.  The entries indicating shutdowns, reboots, etc. are usually maintained by `init`, whereas entries for users would most-probably be placed in `utmp` by `getty` or variants (for console log-ins) or a login-manager like `gdm` (for X11 sessions).  E.g., there's also a `sessreg` program intended to update `utmp` for arbitrary reasons a sysadmin may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

In function `print_utline` from `utmpdump` source code, you can find a litte help:

```
static void print_utline(struct utmp ut, FILE *out)
{
....
    /*       pid    id       user     line     host     addr       time */
fprintf(out, "[%d] [%05d] [%-4.4s] [%-*.*s] [%-*.*s] [%-*.*s] [%-15s] [%-28.28s]\n",
       ut.ut_type, ut.ut_pid, ut.ut_id, 8, UT_NAMESIZE, ut.ut_user,
       12, UT_LINESIZE, ut.ut_line, 20, UT_HOSTSIZE, ut.ut_host,
       addr_string, time_string);
}
```